# reverse java code to UML notation?

Tags: java, uml, reverse-engineering

Class Engine has "start(c:Component)" method. So do we need to draw an association between Engine and Component Class IF there is no "new Component()" inside Engine class.

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans has a UML modelling tool to to reverse engineer java code. See  [Generating UML From the NetBeans IDE](http://blogs.oracle.com/JavaFundamentals/entry/generating_uml_from_the_netbeans) for details.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What do you want me to tell you?

Answer (score 0):

MyEclipse Professional also has a [UML reverse-engineering tool](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/uml/#reverseengineering).